# How to abort a save operation with a WordPress hook?

Tags: hooks

I have a WooCommerce and Dokan website.  I wrote a new plugin that is supposed to do some backend form validation on custom fields before performing an insert or update operation.  I am having problems using PHP code to abort a save operation when form validation fails.  This piece of code [taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797882/wordpress-prevent-post-to-be-saved-if-condition-is-true-with-wp-insert-post-data) is able to abort an INSERT operation

```
function disable_save( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    $maybe_empty = true;

    return $maybe_empty;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'disable_save', 0, 2 );
```

But it does not work for an update operation.

I even went right into the `wp-includes/post.php` file and changed the `wp_update_post()` function to `return 0` on the first line, but it does not prevent the update operation from occurring.

How do I gracefully prevent a save operation with a WordPress hook in a WooCommerce + Dokan project?

Comment: Try `wp_die()`, it stops the current action in wordpress.

Comment: The issue with wp_die() or even just die() is that it seems to stop execution of the script which in turn prevents me from logging the validations errors and printing user friendly error messages in the original form the user submitted their information from.  For example, I want to be able to print an error message "This product is not available between May 1 to December 31 in your province/state" immediately beneath the Product Name custom field that I provided in my form.

Comment: At the moment, I've given up on trying to gracefully fail a save operation while also printing user friendly form messages.  I'm going to take an Ajax approach to doing form validation on custom fields.